# Correct php code

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating my first wordpress theme http://www.designstest.co.uk/ - please visit this page to see blog page IS NOT home page.

At the moment I am using this piece of php to display titles (and hide on homepage).

```
<?php if ( is_front_page() ) { ?>
<h1 style="display: none; height= 0px;"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
 <?php } else { ?>
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
```

But I need news page (blog) to display date and titles to be h5 instead of h1.
How do I specify that?

What I need is:

1. homepage - does not display the title (done. see code above)
2. all pages (static with editable text) do display the title (done. see code above)
3. posts titles on news page (which basically is the blog) to display (done with the code above) but they have to have a different styling from the rest of website. The title styling  for all pages is h1 but for news page I need it to be h5. (don't know how to specify that)
4. date to be displayed only blog posts and nowhere else throughout website. (don't know how to specify that)

I hope this makes more sense now.

I've tried to add elseif and specify things I need for news page but it does not work and it's possibly because I don't know correct php syntax.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Why are you generating html to hide it with CSS ? You could just do `if(!is_front_page())`

Comment: Aside from changing h1 to h5 in the code snippet you posted?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date

Comment: this question is very confused

Comment: Thank you Michael I will try to search there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of filling your php-file with endless amounts of if-statements to display content in different ways depending on post-types or frontpage, use custom page-templates. You can create a page template, name it "frontpage" for example, and use just that file for your front page, and another one for displaying your 'posts'.
Check the codex for more detailed information. http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates

Doing it like you are trying to do now is not exactly considered good practice.

Comment: Thank you ninja. To be honest I am self learner and up until now thought it's better to have one page template instead of few. I will look in to it.

Answer (score 0):

use this function:

```
function is_blog () {
    global $post;
    $posttype = get_post_type($post );
    return ( ((is_archive()) || (is_author()) || (is_category()) || (is_home()) || (is_single()) || (is_tag())) && ( $posttype == 'post') ) ? true : false ;
}
```

Usage:

```
<?php if (is_blog()) { echo 'You are on a blog page'; } ?>
```

taken from: https://gist.github.com/wesbos/1189639

Comment: How does this at all relate to the OP's question?

Comment: He wanted to know, if he is on a blog page the same way as he checks if he is on the frontpage or not. Because wordpress does not have a is_blog() yet, this is a way to implement it yourself.

Comment: Hmm I think this one is bit too advanced for me, but I get the idea behind it. Just it's only for the blog page title, not posts titles right?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!the_title() == "Blog") {
    echo '<h1>'.the_title().'</h1>';
} else {
    echo '<h5>'.the_title().' on '.the_date().'</h5>';
}
```

Comment: Th0masR0ss - it seams to make sense. It's probably not for my situation, but I will save it for the future. Many thanks.

Comment: `the_title()` and `the_date()` are functions that actually `echo` information. Your code is flawed. Always try to explain what the code does, instead of offering a code dump.